# Feedback on condensing simple python code

Tags: python

I wanted to know if anyone here has any tips on condensing this code while still using basic string methods. The code asks for an user input of their first name and displays the index of the first occurrence of each vowel using a function and simple string methods.
Here is my code:

```
def find_vowel():
    name = input("What is your first name?: ")
    name = name.lower()
    if name.find('a') > 0:
        print "There is an a in your name, first found at index",name.find('a')
    if name.find('e') > 0:
        print "There is an e in your name, first found at index",name.find('e')        
    if name.find('i') > 0:
        print "There is an i in your name, first found at index",name.find('i')  
    if name.find('o') > 0:
        print "There is an o in your name, first found at index",name.find('o')
    if name.find('u') > 0:
        print "There is an u in your name, first found at index",name.find('u')

find_vowel()
```

Any feedback on condensing the code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [code-review] is better suited for vague improvement requests on working code. Anyway, what about using a for loop?

Comment: `for vowel in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']:`...

Comment: FYI: you should switch to Python 3--Python 2 supports ends this year.

Comment: I'm no python programmer, but obviously each item could be performed by some procedure (function), like `test('a')`, `test('e')`, and so on. Next step would be to put 'a', 'e', ... in a list and iterate over the list calling `test(X)`. If only needed once (inside the loop), you could even avoid the `test` function.  This is a very basic question about procedural programming, BTW.

Comment: Thank you for the responses everyone, appreciate the advice! I'm just starting to learn programming so this question might come as very basic knowledge, but I appreciate the replies.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of repeating all of that code for each vowel, make a loop that takes it in a variable, like this:

```
def find_vowel():
    name = input("What is your first name?: ")
    name = name.lower()
    for vowel in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']:
        if name.find(vowel) > 0:
            print "There is an %c in your name, first found at index" % vowel,name.find(vowel)

find_vowel()
```

Side note: You probably don't want to use `input`, but rather `raw_input`, since you're still on Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to Python 3, where `print` is a function rather than a statement, you can condense this into one line as a list comprehension.

```
>>> def find_vowel():
...     [None for name, vowels in ((input("What is your first name?: ").lower(), 'aeiou'),) for vowel in vowels if vowel in name and print('There is an', vowel, 'in your name, first found at index', name.find(vowel))]
...
>>> find_vowel()
What is your first name?: William
There is an a in your name, first found at index 5
There is an i in your name, first found at index 1
```